# Is it possible to have a struct generic over U and V, where U : V?

Tags: rust

...and V is a trait.
Ie. Something like this, but that works?

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct Foo<U, V: ?Sized> where U : V {
  instance:Option<U>,
  _v: PhantomData<*const V>,
}

impl<U, V> Foo<U, V> {

  /// Create a new instance
  pub fn new() -> Foo<U, V> {
    return Foo {
      instance: None,
      _v: PhantomData,
    };
  }

  /// Return trait
  pub fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&V> {
    return match(self.instance) {
      Some(v) => Some(&v as &V),
      None => None
    };
  }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {

  use super::Foo;

  trait Fooish {
    fn x(&self) -> i32;
  }

  struct Bar;

  impl Fooish for Bar {
    fn x(&self) -> i32 {
      return 0i32;
    }
  }

  #[test]
  fn test_new_foo() {
    let _ = Foo::<Bar, Fooish>::new();
  }
}
```

playpen link: http://is.gd/N7tWwH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately it is not possible (yet, maybe in the future...).

The problem is that the syntax `U: V` is only allowed if `V` is a `trait` and there is no way to declare that a generic parameter is a `trait`; `?Sized` only indicate a type that may not be sized, which allows traits but also other things...

When I [experimented with polymorphism](https://github.com/matthieu-m/rust-poly), the work-around I use was to declare a trait `DerivedFrom`, and then I would check `U: DerivedFrom<V>`. Of course, it requires to implement `DerivedFrom<Trait>` for `Struct`... which is not exactly ergonomic...

You can check it [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11b36ca978e75185df8b):

```
// Scaffolding

pub trait DerivedFrom<T: ?Sized> {}

//
trait SomeTrait {}

struct HelloWorld;

impl SomeTrait for HelloWorld {}
impl DerivedFrom<SomeTrait> for HelloWorld {}

pub struct Foo<U, V: ?Sized> where U: DerivedFrom<V> {
  instance: Option<U>,
  _v: std::marker::PhantomData<*const V>,
}

type HelloFoo = Foo<HelloWorld, SomeTrait>;

fn main() {
}
```

*Note: and of course, for this very reason, we cannot have a blanket impl for `DerivedFrom`.*